# C++ single threaded works, on new thread it calls "abort()"

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I am having an issue that is most likely related to threads or mutex:

When I call a custom method directly in the main method, it works and gives results. However, the calculation takes ~ 900 ms. So I wanted to make a single thread that only does this calculations and shows the results afterwards.

The project is quite big at this time, I try to give pseudo code that is as close as possible to the original one.

More background information: I stream a depth image from a camera and want to use a thinning algorithm on this image. Using OpenCV 3.1.0 and MSVC 2015 for this (all 32 bit).

```
int main()
{
 //init camera, read images etc...
 Mat copyOfImage = dephtImage->clone();
 applyThreadedThinning(&copyOfImage);

 return 0;
}
```

This version works fine.
If I call the method instead like that:

```
std::thread t1(&applyThreadedThinning,&copyOfImage);
```

it says
"Debug Error!

Program: .... *.exe

abort() has been called

(Press Retry to debug the application)"

I can not imagine why it works without a thread, but with a thread it does not.
Debugging is a bit complicated, I just follow every line with "step into" and wait until it makes this error message. Once I isolated the line of code that is responsible for this error, what do I do then?

Comment: have you tried hitting "Retry" to debug the application? and had a look at the stacktrace then?

Comment: If I hit "Retry" it stops at the method "static bool __cdecl issue_debug_notification(wchar_t const* const message) throw()". The stacktrace is the "Call Stack" ?

Comment: well you need to check the previous functions then. If at any point you are at the destructor of the std::thread the answers which are already here explain why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

A c++ std::thread object needs to know what it should do in case it gets destroyed (goes out of scope).

There are 2 options: `join` which waits for the thread to finish or `detach` to detach the thread from the object.

Because both options are valid it was decided that none of the both of them will be implicit on destruction and an assert (abort) will be thrown when you destroy a std::thread object without calling one of those functions first.

If you want to wait for the thread to finish call `t1.join()` before the object goes out of scope.

If you want to detach yourself from the thread and let it finish at some point you don't care about call `t1.detach()` before the object goes out of scope.

Comment: +1 for giving both options, but based on the OP's requirements it sounds like `t1.detach()` is what is needed. Note that in this simple example there won't be any indication provided to the user that the worker thread has completed, because `main()` will exit before the worker thread completes.

Comment: yeah he said this is simplified "pseudo code" so because I don't know the requirements I listed both. It really depends on the situation though.

Comment: The detach() did help me. My main thread is in a while loop as long as I do not hit a key. It seems the thread is being started again, while the old one is not finished yet. Also while debugging, I noticed that there are some problems with the scope (pointer to image is null pointer, but on single threaded it is not a null pointer). I need to read more about this topic and try again.

Comment: `detach` does that. it detaches. while join waits. You need to decide for one of the 2 functionalities. c++11 threads are all about clean thread handling. You also cannot easily "kill" threads from outside. Threads need to be able to end themselves by going out of scope. So no infinite loops in threads etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait in the main function until the thread finishes.

```
...
t1.join();
return 0;
```

Comment: a `join` waits for the thread to finish. Does you thread end at some point?

Comment: It seems that is the problem. The single threaded method returns result normally. If I start the same method within an own thread, the thread does not finish for some reason. As mentioned above, I think it is related to "out of scope".

Answer (score 0):

Solved the abort() problem. The issue seems to be related to scopes/smart pointers. Simply replace every cv::Mat* with cv::Mat (no pointers) and adapt the code for the changed type.

For my case that was a solution. Thanks for the explaining @Hayt, it did really speed up my process.